# SQL Find duplicated names and count it for each status

Tags: mysql, sql

I found 85 duplicated names in my base with

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(*) 
FROM Tab 
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC, 1;
```

with the result set:

```
Name    COUNT(*)
a   28
b   12
c   10
d   8
e   5
f   4
g   3
h   3
i   2
...
```

My concern is to sort these duplicated names (303 entries in total) per status

```
SELECT Status, COUNT(*) FROM Tab
WHERE Name IN (SELECT Name FROM Tab GROUP BY Name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
GROUP BY Status
ORDER by Name;
```

give me this result:

```
Status  COUNT(*)
Ended   38
Deleted 21
InUse   244
```

Now I would like a combinaison of both queries meaning to show the duplicated names counted by status.

| Name | Ended | Deleted | InUse |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 6 | 2 | 20 |
| b | 0 | 0 | 12 |
| c | 0 | 8 | 2 |
| d | 6 | 1 | 1 |
| e | 4 | 0 | 1 |
| f | 0 | 3 | 1 |
| g | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| h | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| i | 1 | 0 | 1 |

If I can have an extra column as Total will be great also but my main goal is to build a query for this result set

Comment: https://www.databasestar.com/mysql-pivot/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of Nathan_Sav's suggestion -

```
SELECT
    Name,
    SUM(Status = 'Ended') AS Ended,
    SUM(Status = 'Deleted') AS Deleted,
    SUM(Status = 'InUse') AS InUse,
    COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM Tab 
GROUP BY Name 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY InUse DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Window function For Calculation Count and Create To Result with Pivot

This Code work to use sql server

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@scols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([Status])  from Tab
                 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE  ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')   ,1,1,'' )
 
 
select @scols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME([Status]) +',''0'') as '+  QUOTENAME([Status])
                 from Tab  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE  ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')  ,1,1,'')
 

 set @query = 'SELECT   Name,'+@scols+' from 
             (
               
                select Name,[Status],CounStatus,Total
                from (
                select *,count(*) over (partition by Name,[Status]) as CounStatus
                ,count(*) over (partition by Name ) as Total
                ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Name,[Status] order by [Status]) as rw
                from  Tab
                )d
                where  rw=1

            ) x
            pivot 
            (
               sum( CounStatus)  for [Status] in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
            
            '

execute(@query)
```

You can to insert the basic data with the following codes

```
create table Tab(Name nvarchar(100),Status nvarchar(100))
insert into tab (Name,Status)
select 'a' as Name,'Ended' as Status
go 6

insert into tab (Name,Status)
select 'a','Deleted'
go 2

insert into tab (Name,Status)
select 'a','InUse'
go 20

insert into tab (Name,Status)
select 'b','InUse'
go 12


insert into tab (Name,Status)
select 'c','Deleted'
go 8

insert into tab (Name,Status)
select 'c','InUse'
go 2

select Name,[Status],CounStatus,Total
from (
select *,count(*) over (partition by Name,[Status]) as CounStatus
,count(*) over (partition by Name ) as Total
,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Name,[Status] order by [Status]) as rw
from  Tab
)d
where  rw=1
```